# Windows 8 Store App, Can't Use WCF Data Service

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-8, windows-store-apps, wcf-data-services

I create a Windows 8 Store App and try to link to my WCF Data Service
here is the code:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://10.0.1.16:8080/CloudEDUServer/CourseService.svc");
CourseService.CloudEDUEntities ctx = new CourseService.CloudEDUEntities(uri);
try
{
    var result = from crs in ctx.COURSE_OK
                 where crs.TITLE == "Test Title3"
                 select crs;
    var result1 = result.FirstOrDefault();   //HERE COMES THE BUG!!!!
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("{0}", result1.TITLE);

}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

and when it goes in the line where i mark a comment "HERE COMES THE BUG", the program throws an exception, here is the log:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.WindowsStore.DLL

I've downloaded the WCF Data Service Tools for Windows 8 Store App and also, when I write a common command line app with the same code, it works well.
What should I do?Can anyone tell me how to fix this bug?

Comment: Did you add the proper capabilities to your appxmanifest? Given the Uri that you are using, you'll need `Internet (Client)` and `Private Networks (Client & Server)` at a minimum.

Comment: Add a '.ToList()' to result to force the results to be enumerated. As it is now, it could be either first query, or your `.FirstOrDefault()` throwing the exception. What do you get if you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Large God Ren. Windows store app only supports async WCF Data Service. [You can get answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617042/any-sample-on-how-to-use-wcf-ria-services-in-xaml-metro-app)