# Windows store app, WCF Data Service InvalidOperationException when calling DataServiceQuery.EndExecute()?

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-8, windows-store-apps, wcf-data-services

I lookup relative data find that Windows store app only support async WCF calling to ensure the responsive UI. [Here is a relative question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617042/any-sample-on-how-to-use-wcf-ria-services-in-xaml-metro-app)

I achieve my data service and do like that. Here is the code:

```
MyDataServiceContext ctx = new MyDataServiceContext(uri);

DataServiceQuery<COURSE_OK> query =
        (DataServiceQuery<COURSE_OK>)(from crs in ctx.COURSE_OK
                                      select crs);

TaskFactory<IEnumerable<COURSE_OK>> tf = new TaskFactory<IEnumerable<COURSE_OK>>();
var result = await tf.FromAsync(query.BeginExecute(null, null),
                                ira => query.EndExecute(ira)); // InvalidOperationException

foreach (var a in result)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("{0}", a.TITLE);
}
```

I succeeded only once, after that it always crash in query.EndExecute(ira) method and said InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code.

In addition, it works well in Console Application. I guess that the main problem is Windows store app, but how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your function looks quite good. This is what works for me:

```
var queryTask = Task.Factory.FromAsync<IEnumerable<TResult>>(query.BeginExecute(null, null), (asResult) =>
{
   var result = query.EndExecute(asResult).ToList();
   return result;
});
```

Maybe you should not initialize your context on every call. Just initialize it once and reuse it every time you need it.